# Update same input name using backbone.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, backbone.js

How to update multiple input with the same name using backbone.js.
I just want to update each input per td with their corresponding doc_id using jquery.
ANy suggestion or help...

Here is my html code:

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="doc_id"/>
<input type="text" class="abc" name="docs_nos[]" id="inputDocs_nos" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="date_issued[]" id="inputstart" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="date_expired[]" id="inputend" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="remaks[]" id="inputRemaks" value="" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="doc_id"/>
<input type="text" class="abc" name="docs_nos[]" id="inputDocs_nos" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="date_issued[]" id="inputstart" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="date_expired[]" id="inputend" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy" value=""/> 
<input type="text" class="abc" name="remaks[]" id="inputRemaks" value="" />
</td>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
saveDocs: function(e) {
  var that = this
  var d = array;
  $.map($('input.abc, select.abc').serializeArray(), function(n, i) {
   d[n['name']] = n['value'];
  });

  documents = new Documents();
  documents.set('id', $('input[type=hidden]').val());

  documents.save(d, {
    success: function (model, response) {
       alert = new AlertView({type: 'success', message: 'Update success.'});
       alert.render();
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
       alert = new AlertView({type: 'error', message: response});
       alert.render();
    }
  });  
}
```

Comment: I think you should create `array` of `doc_id` like `doc_id[]`. Is there any working demo, like on **Fiddle**.

Comment: It will be easier if every table row is bound to sub-view and a matching model (part of a collection).